# Timing in python turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

Hi i want to make fun in python turtle that will measure time from start of program to the moment that user will click on space
my code looks like this and i have problem with moment when i calculate the time

```
import turtle
import time

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(600,600)
t = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
t.speed(3)
time = time.time()

def prawy():
    t.setheading(0)
    t.fd(50)

def lewo():
    t.setheading(180)
    t.fd(50)

def gora():
    t.setheading(90)
    t.fd(50)

def dol():
    t.setheading(270)
    t.fd(50)

def spac(x):
    print(round(time.time()-x,2))


turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(prawy, 'Right')
turtle.onkey(lewo, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(gora, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(dol, 'Down')
turtle.onkeypress(spac, 'space')

turtle.mainloop()
```

i know i have to put the time from begining to my fun but i have no idea how
THX for support

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **daemon thread** that goes through **all the code**, and you could write the function to print the time as of the press of space bar.

**The thread:**

```
import threading
import time
Score=0

def Start_Timer():
    global Score
    time.sleep(1)
    Score=Score+1
Timer=threading.Thread(target=Start_Timer, daemon=True)
Timer.start()
```

**The code that presents the time at the end:**

```
def spac():
    print("{0}".format(Score))
```

**Combine it with your previous code:**

```
import turtle
import time
import threading

Score=0

def Start_Timer():
    global Score
    time.sleep(1)
    Score=Score+1
Timer=threading.Thread(target=Start_Timer, daemon=True)
Timer.start()

def prawy():
    t.setheading(0)
    t.fd(50)

def lewo():
    t.setheading(180)
    t.fd(50)

def gora():
    t.setheading(90)
    t.fd(50)

def dol():
    t.setheading(270)
    t.fd(50)

def spac():
    print("{0}".format(Score))


turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(prawy, 'Right')
turtle.onkey(lewo, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(gora, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(dol, 'Down')
turtle.onkeypress(spac, 'space')

turtle.mainloop()
```

Also thanks for *Bialomazur* and *cdlane* for providing beforehand information!

Ps. This is my first time answering other questions, so I sincerely apologize if there is any errors (I am not that experienced and that was the best I could do. :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can't define arbitrary arguments for event handlers -- their argument signatures are defined by turtle, not you.  So you need to subtract the global that contains the start of time, not the invalid argument to `spac()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time

def prawy():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.fd(50)

def lewo():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.fd(50)

def gora():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.fd(50)

def dol():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.fd(50)

def spac():
    print(round(time.time() - start, 2))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)

turtle = Turtle('turtle')
turtle.speed('slow')

screen.onkey(prawy, 'Right')
screen.onkey(lewo, 'Left')
screen.onkey(gora, 'Up')
screen.onkey(dol, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(spac, 'space')

screen.listen()

start = time.time()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell there's **no variable** with the name **x** declared in your code.

Furthermore you should **not** name a **variable** like a **module** that you are importing, thus change
the variable name of **time** to **t1**.

Also change the function **spac(x)** to:

```
def spac():
   global t1

   print(round(time.time()-t1,2))
```

take care

Comment: Despite the down vote, this is a reasonable answer.  Except for the use of `global` of course.